# Humidity query with actions on google

Tags: actions-on-google

I have a live app but the problem is that I can't get humidity device queries working. It just makes a simple google search.

Here's the JSON for a sync for a temp/humidity sensor device (temp query works fine) :

```
{
    "id": "123",
    "name": {
        "defaultNames": [
            "TestHum"
        ],
        "name": "TestHum"
    },
    "willReportState": true,
    "otherDeviceIds": [
        {
            "agentId": "4321",
            "deviceId": "123"
        }
    ],
    "type": "action.devices.types.SENSOR",
    "attributes": {
        "queryOnlyHumiditySetting": true,
        "temperatureUnitForUX": "C",
        "queryOnlyTemperatureControl": true
    },
    "traits": [
        "action.devices.traits.TemperatureControl",
        "action.devices.traits.HumiditySetting"
    ],
    "customData": {
        "WhatAmI": "abc",
        "Who": "123"
    }
}
```

Can someone let me know what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: What is the exact text of the query you are asking? What is the name of the device? Can you please add how does your Query response looks like?

Comment: there's no query response - it runs a web search. i can get it to work if i put the device in a Room in the Home app and ask for the humidity of the room, but not the individual device - raised it with the google issue tracker, feels like a bug to me

Comment: Oh - yes, I have encountered that too, but I'm surprised that the temperature works.

Comment: Link to the corresponding issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/161297467